# Azure Event grid delivery failure due to timeout

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

We are using an Azure Function to publish and Event to Azure Event Grid, which is hooked up to multiple subscribers.  For some reason all our events result in a delivery failure with the error status of InternalServer error with an errorMessage of 'The operation timed out'. This timeout seems to occur very quickly. We are using the EventGridSchema and we have tried with and without filters. Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 0):

We were using a service plan in separate VNets so we think that is the issue but have not tested. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1P0OY.png]